# Is it possible to create a Dynamo DB table with at rest encryption enabled via the Java SDK

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

As I understand it, it's not possible to enable at rest encryption after a table has been created. I currently use the Java SDK to create tables but can't see any way to request the table to be created with encryption turned on.

I've used the latest SDK:

```
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
<version>1.11.391</version>
```

And classes `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.CreateTableRequest` and `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.util.TableUtils#createTableIfNotExists`.

I know another option to create tables would be to use something like the CLI or [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dynamodb_table.html). However, what I liked about the Java SDK API was that it colocates the "schema" right there in the code along with the Java POJO mappings that use it, making it easy to run in tests against the local dynamo db. If I need to write terraform files or scripts to call the CLI these kind of fall "out of band" with the actual code that uses it which feels less ideal.

Is there any way to do this with the Java SDK?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/CreateTableRequest.html#withSSESpecification-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.SSESpecification- ...?

Comment: Thank you yes, I needed to update to the latest SDK version. Now I have access to this method, my previous version didn't have this. Awesome, I'll mark as accepted answer if you add it there.